# How to display search icon on right side through css?

Tags: html, css

I want to display search icon image on the right side through css, but unable to do so. Here's the code:

CSS:

```
.search {
    background: url(../images/icons/search.png) no-repeat;
    display:inline;
    vertical-align:-0px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="sidebar-nav" id="MainMenu">
    <li style="border-bottom:none">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="images/logo.png">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="left">
        <a href="#">
            <input type="text" class="search" style="border: 0">
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: tried using `background-position: right center;` ?

Comment: background: url("http://lorempixel.com/16/16/") no-repeat top right;

Comment: @Miam - its not clear where you are having trouble. Could you update your question with the information? I think this could be a good question, but it might be closed because its not clear what's currently happening and why its wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/kzoctad0/)**

css

```
.search {
    position:relative;
    top:2px;
    /* readujst in jsfiddle */
    padding:8px 5px 8px 30px;
    background:white url(http://i.imgur.com/lFkqn.png) right center no-repeat;
}
```

and your corrected html

```
<ul class="sidebar-nav" id="MainMenu">
    <li style="border-bottom:none">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="images/logo.png"/>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="left">
        <a href="#">
            <input type="text" class="search" style="border: 0" />
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the position `top right` and try like this.

```
 .search {
     background: url(../images/icons/search.png) no-repeat top right;
     display:inline;
     vertical-align:0px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using a background image then you can move your bg image  to `right` and `left.` In addition you no need to add `display:inline;`.

Also I found your HTML markup is not valid; Closing `</li>` is missing. In addition you are wrapping `input` element inside `a` tag.

```
 .search {background: url("http://lorempixel.com/16/16/") no-repeat top right; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
      .search {
         background: url(../images/icons/search.png) no-repeat top right;
         display:inline;
         vertical-align:-0px;
        }
```